# PHP combine array based on value, add 0 if no match

Tags: php, arrays

I have seen tons of questions that discuss portions of my question, but have been unable to work them into a solution. Hopefully someone can help me out.

I have two arrays, I'll call them `Quantity` and `Shipping`.

---

Here is `Quantity`:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Fed-Ex
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => 2
            [1] => USPS
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [0] => 1
            [1] => USPS-E
        )
)
```

`[0]` is the quantity, and `[1]` is the name.

---

And here is `Shipping`:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Fed-Ex
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => 1
            [1] => USPS
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [0] => 11
            [1] => USPS-A
        )
    [3] => Array(
            [0] => 10
            [1] => USPS-E
        )
)
```

`[0]` is the index, and `[1]` is the name.

---

I would like to combine them based on `index 1` matches into something that looks like this. If there is no match I would like a 0 to be inserted instead (like in my `USPS-A` example).

I'll call it `Master`:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Fed-Ex
            [2] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => 1
            [1] => USPS
            [2] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [0] => 11
            [1] => USPS-A
            [2] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array(
            [0] => 10
            [1] => USPS-E
            [2] => 1
        )
)
```

`[0]` is the index, `[1]` is the name, and `[2]` is the quantity.

---

Does anyone have any suggestions? I tried using nested `foreach loops` but I was ending up with duplicates even when I used `break` statements. Tried `array_column` and `in_array` as well but to no success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that the `shipping` array will always be bigger than the `quantity`, here is something that works.

```
$quantities = [
    [1, 'Fex-Ex'],
    [2, 'USPS'],
    [1, 'USPS-E']
];

$shippings = [
    [3, 'Fex-Ex'],
    [1, 'USPS'],
    [11, 'USPS-A'],
    [10, 'USPS-E'],
];

$master = array();
foreach ($shippings as $shipping) {
    $qty = 0;
    foreach ($quantities as $quantity) {
        if ($shipping[1] == $quantity[1]) {
            $qty = $quantity[0];
        }
    }
    $master[] = array(
        $shipping[0],
        $shipping[1],
        $qty
    );
}

var_dump($master);
```

Comment: Thank you - this does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested loops to do this. You can just loop over each of the arrays once.

First, iterate the `$shipping` array to build the `$master` array using the `[1]` key (name) as its index. You can add a zero value for quantity at index 2 at the same time.

```
foreach ($shipping as $s) {
    $master[$s[1]] = $s + [2 => 0];
}
```

Second, iterate the `$quantity` array to update the quantity values in `$master`.

```
foreach ($quantity as $q) {
    $master[$q[1]][2] = $q[0];
}
```

Keep in mind that with this approach, using the names as keys, if there are duplicate names they will be overwritten.

Comment: Very ingenious. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would do the job (without nested loops):

```
<?php 

$quantities = [
    [1, 'Fed-Ex'],
    [2, 'USPS'],
    [1, 'USPS-E']
];

$shippings = [
    [3, 'Fed-Ex'],
    [1, 'USPS'],
    [11, 'USPS-A'],
    [10, 'USPS-E'],
];

foreach($quantities as &$v) {
    $quantities[$v[1]] = $v[0];
    unset($v);
}

$master = [];

foreach($shippings as $v) {
    $master[] = [
        $v[0], 
        $v[1], 
        isset($quantities[$v[1]]) ? $quantities[$v[1]] : 0
    ];
}
```